# Can progressive web apps access android file system

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, security, telegram

I see there are a lot of articles about the restrictions imposed on javascript in windows chrome. It can't access the file system of a user without the user himself uploading it to the server of the pwa. But I see none about javascript running on android chrome. Are there the same restrictions on javascript in android chrome as that of windows? For example I open a pwa on my chrome, suppose telegram, so will telegram be able to access my files like my photos, videos, documents, etc without my permission? Ik it can't happen on windows. Javascript aside, is there any way for a pwa to access the files on my android storage without my permission? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Writable File System APIs](https://web.dev/file-system-access/) for this.

Comment: Ik about native file system access api. But it's not supported in android chrome according to me and it requires the user to input the file or drag and drop it. But I a m talking about android that is there a way for a pwa to access filesystem of android without user permission like input or drag and drop.